# Can I create the default SharePoint 2010 page for an upgraded content DB?

Tags: 2010, 2007, default

I moved from MOSS 2007 to SharePoint Foundations and will be moving to 2013 after. There was a lot of customization done in 2007 and I am trying to put it back to default where possible. I had problems with the default.aspx after upgrade so I just deleted and created bare-bones one.

When a new SharePoint 2010 site is created (no upgrade) it would look a certain way and have links to all the other sites. Is it possible to create that or copy it from somewhere to move to the root of our SharePoint installation?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating another site, took the code from the home.aspx and pasted it into my actual site which got me what I wanted.